# How To Find a Value and Use it in PHP?

Tags: php, numbers

My goal is to do this :

1. Get the value from variable
2. Check the value
3. Change to thousands depending on the value
4. Use the new value.

Example :

```
$input = 12345

//Code to detect input is in thousands or hundreds 
$input = 12345 ==> $change = 12000 / 10000
```

My Goal is to achieve $change, where the code could detect the input and return whether or not it's in hundreds or thousands and so forth.

The Answer I arrived in after combining all of your opinions :

```
$maxBarChart= max($countBarChart1,$countBarChart2,$countBarChart3); //The inputs
$length = strlen(strval($maxBarChart)); // Get the length

//Checks
if($length==1){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/1);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*1)+5;
}
elseif($length==2){                                                
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/10);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*10)+50;    
}
elseif($length==3){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/100);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*100)+500;    
}
elseif($length==4){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/1000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*1000)+5000;    
}
elseif($length==5){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/10000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*10000)+50000;    
}
elseif($length==6){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/100000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*100000)+500000;    
}
elseif($length==7){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/1000000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*1000000)+5000000;    
}
elseif($length==8){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/10000000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*10000000)+50000000;    
}
elseif($length==9){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/100000000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*100000000)+500000000;    
}
elseif($length==10){
       $numberBarChart = floor($maxBarChart/1000000000);
       $totalBarChart = ($numberBarChart*1000000000)+5000000000;    
}
```

Although it's crude and inefficent but the code works and achieved what I was aiming for, the post was made to find out about the floor function and strlen idea.

Thank You Everyone who advised and answered my post.

Comment: If I understand, you only want to know if the number is hundreds, thousands etc...?

Comment: Can you share some examples of input and output?

Comment: `pow(10,floor(log10($input)))`

Comment: You could always.... `$whats = match(strlen((string) $input)) { 1 => 'ones', 2 => 'tens', 3 =>'hundreds', 4 => 'thousands', 5 => 'tens-o-thousands', 6 => 'hundreds-o-thousands', 7 => 'one million dollars or more', default => 'tooo much' };` ... and cast to int first if you expect floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *floor()* function and divide by 1000 to get the number of thousands in your input :

```
$change = floor($input/1000) //12
```

The same way, you get the number of hundreds :

```
$change = floor($input/100) //123
```

If the result is 0 (with an input of 143 for example), that means there is no thousand in it. You should divide by 10 and try it out with 100 :

```
if(floor($input/1000) == 0) {

    if(floor($input/100 == 0)) {

        //...

    }

} else {

    $change = floor($input/1000);

}
```

You may do the same into a *for* loop with a step of /10 to try thousands, hundreds etc.

If you need to get the rest, use the modulo operator.

For example, 120 % 100 = 20. Also, 12345 % 10000 = 2345.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether or not the input is in thousands or hundred ? Because the input could range from 1 to billions.

Comment: $change = floor($input/1000) //must be between 1 and 9 for 1000 to 9000. Do the same with hundreds (/100)